# Wrong display of html e-mail in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I created an html e-mail with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">

<div style="background-color:orange;max-width:600px;height:180px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

<img src="http://placehold.jp/500x710.png" style="height:180px;width:127px;display:block;border:0;float:right;margin:0px;padding:0px;">

<p style="font-size:40px;padding-left:10px;margin-top:0px;padding-top:40px;">This is my important<br>html test</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tested this code with `Outlook 2016 (Win 7)` and I'm getting an unexpected result.

On `Outlook 2016 (Win 7)` the html gets rendered like this:

[image]

instead of the expected like this:

[image]

Is this a known Outlook problem? How can I fix it?

Using an image with 127x180 results to the same, only the image is smaller.

Answer (score 3):

- `<div>` is problematic in Outlook. It doesn't really work well with it and it's best to avoid it.
- `max-width` is ignored by Outlook.
- `padding-top` is ignored by Outlook.
- Outlook ignores `width` and `height` in a style sheet. Use `<img width="180" />` instead.

This works consistently across every email client. It may not be the way I would code an email, I would rather put the image and text in their own `<td>` for better manipulation, but based on your important html test, I wanted to demonstrate a way to make things work.

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" style="padding: 20px; background-color:orange;">
      <img src="http://placehold.jp/500x710.png" width="127" height="180" align="right"   style="display:block;">
      <p style="font-size: 40px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 0px;">This is my important<br>html test</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If the window is smaller than 600px, the image gets cutted. Instead the whole table should get smaller and fit the window width. How can I do that?

Comment: @David You can add `width` and `max-width` to the inline style sheet. Outlook will ignore them, just like I said. Or you can add `@media` queries to a style sheet  which Outlook also ignores.