# HTML Email Signature CSS Not Working in Some Email Clients

Tags: html, css, email

I'm trying to create a html based email signature with tables.

It's definitely working in html, works when I copy and paste into gmail, however when I copy into Outlook, the CSS break. Did I do something wrong here?

```html
<table style="width: 500px; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; line-height:normal;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
 <tr> 
  <td style="width:86px; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle">
   <a href="#" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="Logo" height="auto" width="148" style="width:148px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://i.imgur.com/1HlZfl8.png"></a>
   
  </td>
  

  <td style="width:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle">
   <div style="margin-left:15px"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mNNR1Ga.png"></div>
  </td>
  <td style="width:500px; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td style="font-size:12pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #3d3c3f; padding-bottom:3px;"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b;">Jessica Smith</span>
      <span style="font-size:9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b;"> | CEO/Founder</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="font-size:9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #9b9b9b; padding-bottom:1px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b;"><div style="font-weight:bold; display: inline-block; width: 15px;">t </div>(07) 3281 0000</span><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b"></span><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b; margin-left:10px;"><div style="font-weight:bold; display: inline-block; width: 15px;">f</div>(07) 3281 0000</span>
     </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
     <td width="20px" style="font-size:9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #9b9b9b; padding-bottom:1px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b; "><div style="font-weight:bold; display: inline-block; width: 15px;">e </div><a href="#" style="color: #006f71;">info@domainnamehere.com.au</a></span>
     </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
     <td style="font-size:9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #9b9b9b; padding-bottom:1px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3b;"><div style="font-weight:bold; display: inline-block; width: 15px;">w </div><a href="#" style="color: #006f71;">domainnamehere.com.au</a></span>
     </td>
    </tr>       
    
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:500px; padding-top:16px;" colspan="3" width="500">
   <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" alt="Banner" width="500" style="width:500px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://i.imgur.com/NBxWjRC.png"></a>
  </td>
 </tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Gmail Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUHUl.png)
[Outlook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp1fN.png)

Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, Outlook can be a bit of a pita to style emails in. I'd recommend using a [pre-built framework like foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html) to help avoid spending time troubleshooting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54168230/wrong-display-of-html-e-mail-in-outlook/54172410#54172410

Answer (score 1):

Email clients does not strictly follow HTML Standards. The viewing technology of a typical email client isn't as up-to-date as a web browser. You need to be careful about that. HTML code works in your browser may not work on Email Clients.

You may want to read [Mailchimps Article](https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/) and visit [this link](https://caniuse.email/) for the [CSS Support](https://caniuse.email/)