# HTML Email Signature Column Float Right

Tags: html, css

Creating an email signature.

Currently it looks as expected in a browser.

However when I copy this in to an email client as a signature the right hand column "#float-me-right" wont float right. Could someone please advise the best practice to keep this fixed along the right hand side of the table.

kindest regards

```html
<table class="footer-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width: 1900px; font-family: Trebuchet MS,Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Sans,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-size: 15px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col">
        <img width="280" border="0" src="http://stevenmacdonald.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/team-chris-500x400-1.gif" alt="Hello">
        <p style="margin:0"><a name="_MailAutoSig"><strong style="font-size: 21px;font-weight: 100;line-height:28px; color: #728bfc; margin-left: 12px;">Name</strong></a></p>
        <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px; font-weight: 100; margin-left: 12px;">Job Title</p>
        <p style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; margin-left: 12px; margin-bottom: 0;">07123456789
          <br><span style="color: #000 !important;">test@test.com</span></p>
      </td>

      <td id="float-me-right" class="col" style="text-align: right;">
        <table class="inner-table" style="width: 320px; text-align: right; margin-top: 131px; text-align: left; display: inline-block;">
          <tbody>
            <!-- top row right -->
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span><img border="0" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; display:inline-block; width:120px;" src="http://stevenmacdonald.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Screenshot-2020-02-18-at-16.57.16.png" alt="Hello"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- bottom row right -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0;">Address Top Line<br> addresss line one<br> addresss line two<br> addresss line three<br>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span style="display: inline-block; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; padding-top: 18px;">0151 012 0192<br>
                info@mywebsite.co.uk<br>
                <a href="mywebsite.co.uk" target="_blank" style="color: #728bfc;">mywebsite.co.uk</a></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenmacdonald180/5L8myxnv/9/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340353/html-email-signature-css-not-working-in-some-email-clients

Comment: @stemac check the below link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `float:right` try using table property `align="right"`. That will make your table align right. Check the codepen link.

[`Email Signature`](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/YzXGmdO)

Comment: so this looks great in a browser but then copy and pasting it in to an email signature in eg outlook it no longer holds its shape.

Comment: you have to set table width in `px` for that. then it will remain same, currently it is taking full width.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using tables, it's better to use table properties as first priority instead of CSS.
Try using the align="right" in the table element which you want to align right.

```
align="right"
```

Do let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this didnt work for me.